# a question about normal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

> Let $A$ be a normal matrix and $\lambda$ a scalar.
>
> Show that $A-\lambda I$ is also a normal matrix.

$A$ is a normal matrix then there is a unitary diagonalization of $A$ over $\mathbb{C}$. This means that there is $P$ and $D$ such as $P^*AP=D$.

I'm not sure how to continue from here.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried checking if $(A-\lambda I)^{\ast}$ and $(A-\lambda I)$ commute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Notice that $(A-\lambda I)^*=A^*-\overline \lambda I$ and that $I$ commutes with all matrices.